# find $_{\hat{\theta}_{}^{(1)},\hat{\theta}_{}^{(2)}}$

Tags: statistics

If $^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{}^{(1)}−\theta_0] \xrightarrow{L} \tau_1$ and $^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{}^{(2)}−\theta_0] \xrightarrow{L} \tau_2$, find $_{\hat{\theta}_{}^{(1)},\hat{\theta}_{}^{(2)}}$ (in terms of $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$ and $\alpha$).

Where ARE is Asymptotic Relative Efficiency.

Definition of ARE: If $_[\delta_^{(1)}−(\theta_0)]\xrightarrow{L}$ and  $_[\delta_{'}^{(2)}−(\theta_0)]\xrightarrow{L}$, then $_{\delta_^{(1)},\delta_^{(2)}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{′()}{}$
, $n'(n)$ is some function of n which is from the subscription of $\delta_{'}^{(2)}$

For example, for double exponential distribution ($\theta$, b), $f_\theta(x)=\frac{1}{2b}e^{-\frac{|x-\theta|}{b}}$

$\delta^{(1)}=M_n$ that $\sqrt{n}(M_n-\theta)\xrightarrow{L}N(0,\frac{1}{4(f_\theta(\theta))^2})=N(0,b^2)$

and $\delta^{(2)}=\bar{X}_n$ that $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\theta)\xrightarrow{L}N(0, \sigma^2)=N(0,2b^2)$
by $Var(x_i)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x_i-\theta)^2\frac{1}{2b}e^{-\frac{|x-\theta|}{b}}dx=2b^2$

so, $\sqrt{2n}(\bar{X}_{2n}-\theta)\xrightarrow{L}N(0, \sigma^2)=N(0,2b^2)$

so, $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_{2n}-\theta)\xrightarrow{L}N(0, \sigma^2)=N(0,b^2)$

Here, we have $n'(n) = 2n$

so, $ARE_{M_n, \bar{X}_n}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n'(n)}{n}=\frac{2n}{n}=2$

How do I write $_{\hat{\theta}_{}^{(1)},\hat{\theta}_{}^{(2)}}$ in terms of $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$ and $\alpha$? I have no idea. Please give me some hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We want $k_n[\delta_{n'}^{(2)}-g(\theta_0)] \xrightarrow{L} \tau_1H$

Since $n^\alpha[\hat{\theta}_n^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L}\tau_2H$

$\Rightarrow \frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2}n^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_n^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L}\tau_1H$

$\Rightarrow (\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2}n)^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2}n}^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L}\tau_2H$ because we can use $n'$ to represent $\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2}n$

$\Rightarrow (\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2})^{\alpha}(n)^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{n'}^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L}\tau_2H$

$\Rightarrow (\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2})^{\alpha}(\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}(n)^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{n'}^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L} (\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\tau_2H$

$\Rightarrow (\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2})(n)^{\alpha}[\hat{\theta}_{n'}^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L} (\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\tau_2H$

Since $(\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2})(n)^\alpha[\hat{\theta}_n^{(2)}-\theta_0]\xrightarrow{L}\tau_1H$

So, $$\tau_1=(\frac{\tau_1}{\tau_2})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\tau_2$$

we have $ARE_{\hat{\theta}_n^{(1)},\hat{\theta}_n^{(2)}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\tau_2}{\tau_1}=(\frac{\tau_2}{\tau_1})^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$